# How to push the current branch on a new created remote branch

Tags: git, version-control

When developing using git I often face the following problem.

I need to fix a bug/add a small feature so I do not create an extra branch for it. I work on the developing/staging branch ready to commit it and push it when its done.

At some point I am stuck (or my working day is over)so I want to push the current state on the remote to ask collegues if they can have a look at it. Of course I am not directly pushing into the developing branch so I am:

- creating a new branch ( `git checkout -b tempbranch`)
- pushing it to the remote (`git push origin tempbranch`)
- deleting the branch local (`git branch -d tempbranch`)

I was wondering if there is a shortcut or an easier solution for that? Something like `git push origin develop:tempbranch` without changing the develop branch.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you can do, as long as the `tempbranch`  exists and you are not generating conflicts with your push.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use tags for this as tags are the one made to mark states:

```
$ git tag john_state_21122012
```

than push it

```
$ git push origin john_state_21122012
or
$ git push --tags
```

You don't have to remove tags, keep them there for history.

Comment: hm but then I would have a state on a developing branch which is not stable.This is actually what I want to avoid. The development branch for example contains always the current development state but does not have any major bugs or blocker/crashes and especially has no compile errors.But I want to show the current state to colleagues which could also have compile errors.

Comment: have nt you a personal remote repo?

Comment: no, there is only one remote repo, but you also could push any "personal" branches (also for backup) on it.